# VBox guest local port forwarding

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Debian Guest OS I want to SSH into. I'm just using NAT as my network adapter. I only need to access the VM from my local Host machine. When setting up Port forwarding in the network tab it exposes the port for the entire network and not only the Host. How can I expose the VM to only my Host machine?

Comment: With VBOX NAT you cannot do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @John how can I do it than?

Comment: Virtual Machines offer NAT, Bridged, and Host Only network types commonly so it seems to me that virtual machines will not solve what you are trying to do.  You can try Host Only but that tends to isolate the VM.  Connection to Host will be fine

Comment: @John Ok, cool I've just read through https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html. As far as I understand it always exposes the port to the outside world instead of mapping it to loopback. So for my situation it should be enough to forbid the "Virtual Box Virtual Machine" in the Windows Firewall?? (This is of course not Ideal since if I ever want to expose another machine, I can't.)

Comment: Another thing: I've now forbid "Virtual Box Virtual Machine" in Windows Firewall and i can't access the Guest VM with "ssh -p 2222 usr@192.168.0.91" (2222 is the VBox forwarded SSH port and .91 the Hosts IP), which is what I wanted. On my Host machine " ssh -p 2222 usr@127.0.0.1" connects to the Guest VM as expected, but interestingly using "ssh -p 2222 usr@192.168.0.91" also connects. Shouldn't it also be blocked, since I forbid the App in the Firewall?
 (This is probably obvious, but I'm just not experienced with network config :/ ).